# numpy index access vs numpy.array.item performance

Tags: numpy

I've been using *numpy* for sometime, and was used to access arrays by using the `index` operation, just like python lists, like so:

```py
img = np.zeros((640,480,3))
img[34, 19, 2]
```

However reading a certain book, I came across the [item](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) and [itemset](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemset.html) methods.
According them docs, they provide a performance improvement. However, it is explained at all, at least at the documentation, why that happens.
Does anyone knows the reason of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The difference of speed comes from the **different types** used by `item`/`itemset` and the fact that the `[]` operator is **more generic**. Indeed, both use the built-in `float` type of the Python interpreter while `img[34, 19, 2]` return the python object `np.float64`. Moreover, the `[]` operator support not only direct indexing, but also array sub-views and array filtering, not supported by `item`/`itemset`.

To fully understand why there is a performance difference, one should look in the numpy code. `item` and `itemset` methods respectively call [array_toscalar](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L639) and [array_setscalar](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L705). Alternatively, getting and setting directly an array element respectively calls [array_subscript](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L1505) and [array_assign_subscript](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L1783).

The two last methods are a bit more *costly* because they are more *generic*. Indeed, by looking the difference between `array_toscalar` and `array_subscript`, one can see that the former executes few computations and mainly call [PyArray_MultiIndexGetItem](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2585) which calls [DOUBLE_getitem](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L194), while the later execute more checks and allocations and mainly calls [PyArray_Scalar](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c#L653) which calls [scalar_value](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a3f18fb67c05f2e0a9760216c6d83061be488bf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c#L34) which itself perform an indirect jump to finally produce a `np.float64` object.

Note that although `item` and `itemset` can be faster than the `[]` operator, numpy direct indexing in CPython is still pretty slow. *Numba* can speed it up a lot by performing *native direct indexing*.

Comment: thanks for explanation. Haven't noticed the less generic approach from indexing